# Linear mixed model construction validation

Tags: r, mixed-model, categorical-data, lme4-nlme, nested-data

I have 6 groups of fish made up of 8 individuals. Each group is tested three times under different treatments. These group level treatments are `hungry` , `satiated` and `mixed` in which half of the individuals were hungry and half satiated. I want to test for the effect of group treatment (3 levels, `hungry`, `satiated` and `mixed`) as well as individual state `hungry` or `satiated`. I've run a linear mixed model on just the `mixed` group treatment where `State` was the fixed factor and my random factors were Group and Individual ID nested inside Group. My dependent variable is `mean_speed`.

```
mHvsS = lmer(mean_speed ~ State + (1|Group) + (1|Group/ID), REML=F, 
             data=HungryVsSatiated)
```

but how do appropriately add the Group level treatment (3 factors `hungry`, `satiated` and `mixed`) into the model? Is this correct?

```
mHvsS=lmer(mean_speed ~ Treatment + State + Treatment:State + (1|Group) + ((1|Group/ID), 
           REML=F, data=HungryVsSatiated)
```

Or does `State` need to be nested within `Treatment` as a random factor? I probably also have to throw in `Day` as a random factor, correct?